# Angularjs Reinitializing active controller

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to reinitialize a controller that is currently active ?

This would help me with transitioning from page to page without adding much additional workaround code.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller='Blah as ex'>
   {{ex.name}}
</div>
```

and in the controller Blah's initialization function, the name would be retrieved from a service:

```
this.name = someService.name;
```

So for the example above, I'd like to have a button which would reinitialize my Blah controller.

edit: This is only a basic example.

I'm using the browser's 'state' in order to restore 'back' and 'forward' data  in my controllers.

There are a few cases so I'm trying to simplify its process (which currently works, but is not as 'pretty')

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have the button call the service again? That would refresh the $scope value. I would imagine reloading your entire controller is a lot slower than reloading the individual things you want to update.

Comment: this is a very basic example. My application transitions from one page to another and I need it to reload it's controller.

Comment: To clarify, you are routing to different views and you want the controller for each view to refresh each time you route to it's associated view?

Comment: Yes and no. I don't want to use any angularjs routing.
My current solution works fine but it's not too convenient to document or follow and I'd prefer to see alternatives to it; reloading the controller programmatically seems to me like the best solution. I will give a short description of the issue in an edit in the post ^

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of using angular, but to each his own.

Comment: All I mean by it is angularjs routing is not relevant to my issue  so there's no point to try any solutions that regard it.I have nothing against using routing and I do use it in my application.

Comment: @PatrickMotard consider having a routing for this case. if you route 'shoppingCart' to a controller 'Blah', with template 'blah.html' corresponding to it.Then say there is a link within that 'blah.html' template that still links to 'shoppingCart', but the content that controller 'Blah' should change. The controller will not be re-initialized, even with routing, and the content will stay the same because no routing is actually done (it goes to the same page). I want to be able to change content when clicking the link that's inside the 'blah.html' template

Comment: So it sounds like a user will be adding something to their cart, and then when they click on their cart you would like the cart to reflect the fact that they added/removed said items? So you have a controller for the page of products and a controller for your cart and you're wanting to pass information back and forth between the two?

Comment: @PatrickMotard oh no, please ignore the shopping cart references haha. Thanks but I'm honestly just interested in knowing if it is possible to programmatically reinitialize a currently active controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this be a possible solution? Using route.reload to reload your page?

```
myapp.Controller('SampleController', function($location, $route) {

  $scope.navTo = function(url) {
    if ($location.path() === url) {
      $route.reload();
    } else {
      $location.path(url);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: This does work, but there would be 2 main issues with it that I can think of, first it would reload all the html headers overall, so not only the controller. This would make it much more inefficient. 

The second issue being that the path of the SPA might not reload in the correct place; of course, this is a side-issue.

Comment: I mean the only other thing I can think of is simply adding an initialize function in your controller that resets all values back to default state.

Comment: Solved my issue with a different solution. thanks for the help.